# Unable to upload image to amazon service

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload image file to amazon s3 service using bellow method. But it gives an Exception error like this.

1. Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
2. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

   private static URL uploadFile(File file) {

   ```
   try {
       JSONObject jsonObject = ApiConnector.getBucketDetails();
       JSONObject ob = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
       System.out.println("JSon result " + ob.toString());

       fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());


       BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ob.getString("access_key"), ob.getString("secret_key"));
       client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
       newBucket = new Bucket(ob.getString("bucket_name"));
       PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(newBucket.getName(), fileName, file);
       putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
       ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
       objectMetadata.setContentLength(file.length());
       putObjectRequest.withMetadata(objectMetadata);
       client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

       return client.generatePresignedUrl(ob.getString("bucket_name"), fileName, getDate());
   } catch (JSONException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
   }}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project is missing the dependency for commons logging (which might be referenced by one of the other dependencies). Can you try adding the following in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can see the versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging).

**Update**

If your project is not a `maven` project then you need to download `commons logging` jar and put it inside the `lib` directory. You can download the jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2).

Comment: Could you please help me to add that file to my java project. i'm using Netbeans

Comment: Now it gives me an different error.      (1) Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod                (2)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod

Comment: Could you try adding httpclient as well? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2

Comment: And you will also need httpclient-core https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6